# Obtain media from tweets using rtweet

Tags: r, json, twitter, rtweet

I'm using the package [rtweet](https://rtweet.info/) to search all the tweets containing a list of keywords (see sample code below). From these tweets I would like to extract information on whether they included media (ie. photos or videos) or not, and for those that did include media, extract it.

All of this should work using the following code:

**Step1 - Search tweets:**

```
seagrasstweet30day <- search_30day(q = '(posidonia OR poseidonia OR #posidonia OR cymodocea OR cymo OR seagrass) (Gloria OR #Gloria OR temporal OR storm OR llevantada)',
                                   n = 500,
                                   env_name = "research")
```

**Step2 - Filter out all retweets and only keep those with media_url not NA (i.e. with images, as a result):**

```
tweets_images <- seagrasstweet30day %>% 
  filter(is_retweet == F) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(media_url)) %>% 
  select(media_url) %>% 
  unnest()
```

**Step3 - download media.**

Once I have this data set, I would use the function `download.file()`.

---

**PROBLEM:** Most (but not all!!) of the tweets containing media, are filtered out at Step 2 because their media_url column, obtained from the `search_30day()` function, is `NA`. Any ideas on why tweets containing media do not show their media_url? Thanks for any feedback!

**Update:** I'm doing this using a twitter developer "sandbox" account (which is free). Maybe some features, e.g. extracting media_url, are only available to paid accounts? However, I do see non-`NA` media_url for a small subset of tweets...

Comment: Can you provide an example of how/when "tweets containing media are filtered out at Step 2"? I ran your code and everything looks fine to me. Are you suggesting it is a problem with how rtweet is searching the API or how they are returning the data? It does seem like rtweet might have a problem with the has:media search function, something to report at their Github page.

Answer (score 2):

looking at the package rtweet, it looks like you can pre-filter tweets based on presence of images adding this filter in the query (q)

here some examples:

```
Tweet attributes:
• is:retweet ~~ only retweets
• has:mentions ~~ uses mention(s)
• has:hashtags ~~ uses hashtags(s)
• has:media ~~ includes media(s)
• has:videos ~~ includes video(s)
• has:images ~~ includes image(s)
• has:links ~~ includes URL(s)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yep, that works. But the problem is still the same - I can't access the image without knowing its url. In fact, when I use `has:media` in the query, I get lots of tweets, only 3 of which do contain media_url. How is that possible? Where is the media from the rest of tweet stored?

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be working. You can verify this with a line of code that ensures the tweets returned by your search of the API that contained media are the same number as the tweets contained in your `tweets_images` object. I do this in the code below (final line).

```
seagrasstweet30day <- search_tweets(q = '(Gloria OR #Gloria OR temporal OR storm OR llevantada) has:media',
                                   n = 100,
                                   env_name = "research")

tweets_images <- seagrasstweet30day %>% 
  filter(is_retweet == F) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(media_url)) %>% 
  select(media_url) %>% 
  unnest()

# verify works correctly - should be TRUE
nrow(tweets_images) == sum(!is.na(seagrasstweet30day$media_url))
```

If you think there are tweets that `rtweet` is returning `NA` in the `media_url` field when the tweet actually contains media, that is a problem with the package that needs to be reported to the Github page. I might be misunderstand your issue, so please comment if that is the case.

It is also important to know that you might see tweets that have media, but only because it is contained in something they retweeted - your code filters these tweets out currently (`filter(is_retweet == F)`). Providing an example of a tweet `rwteet` is missing would help though - you can use the post's `id` so we can see it too.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your piece of code. So, I think it might be bug, because if I use `has:media` in the query I get 24 tweets (once I've filtered out the retweets). And if I then check how many of these 24 tweets that do have media have a non-NA media_url column, only 3 of them are filtered. You can check this using the piece of code I add in my answer below. Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to clarify the problem below. I want to pull out from Twitter all of the tweets talking about the effects of storm Gloria on the Mediterranean seagrasses *Posidonia oceanica* or *Cymodocea nodosa*. Since I want only tweets with images of the effects of the storm, I add to the query the `has:media` tag.

```
seagrasstweet30day_media_only <- search_30day(q = 'has:media(posidonia OR poseidonia OR #posidonia OR cymodocea OR cymo OR seagrass) (Gloria OR #Gloria OR temporal OR storm OR llevantada)',
                                    n = 5000,
                                    env_name = "research")
```

This results in 460 tweets. However, some of these tweets might in fact be retweets, so I filter them out.

```
tweets_with_media <- seagrasstweet30day_media_only %>% 
  filter(is_retweet == F)
```

And this returns a tibble with 24 unique tweets that have media. However, if I want to download the images from these tweets, I need their url. So I do the following:

```
tweets_with_media_url <- seagrasstweet30day_media_only %>% 
  filter(is_retweet == F) %>%
  filter(!is.na(media_url))
```

Which returns a tibble with ONLY 3 tweets with media_url! Why only 3, if I know there are 24 of them?

As an example, the tweet I posted myself on 2020-01-30 17:52:30, which is correctly pulled out from Twitter and is stored in the tibble `tweets_with_media`, should obviously have a non-NA media_url column...

[image: Example of a tweet with media but with NA in media_url column]

But, as you can check using this piece of code, this is not the case.

```
tweets_with_media %>% 
  filter(screen_name == "jordifpages", status_id == "1222940664029229057") %>% 
  select(screen_name, created_at, media_url) %>% 
  unnest(cols = media_url)
```

This tweet's media_url column is `NA`. Why is that?

Comment: That helps, thanks. `rtweet` has had some issues lately. I can't reproduce your exact search because I dont have the 30 day archive set up, but a quick search of your timeline let me see the tweet you posted (thanks) and my function returns the correct url for the image your supplied. What happens if you run the code below?

`twt <- get_timeline(user = "jordifpages", n = 200)`

`url <- twt$media_url[twt$status_id == "1222940664029229057"]`

`url`

Comment: That's weird... I do get the url then... I guess it must be a bug... I have raised an issue on `rtweet`'s github. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! If you think answer above helped resolve your issue, feel free to accept it and good luck with your research.